# Save value of dynamical counters

Tags: counters

I would like to get the following items organization:

- section A

  - category 1

    - item 1.1
    - item 1.2
  - category 2

    - item 2.1
- section B

  - category 1

    - item 1.3
    - item 1.4
  - category 2

    - item 2.2
    - item 2.3
- section C

  - category 1

    - item 1.5
  - category 2

    - item 2.4
    - item 2.5
    - item 2.6

with a code like:

```
\section{A}
\resetcategories
    \nextcategory
        \myitem{}
        \myitem{}
    \nextcategory
        \myitem{}

\section{B}
\resetcategories
    \nextcategory
        \myitem{}
        \myitem{}
    \nextcategory
        \myitem{}
        \myitem{}

\section{C}
\resetcategories
    \nextcategory
        \myitem{}
    \nextcategory
        \myitem{}
        \myitem{}
        \myitem{}
```

So there is one dynamical item counter within each dynamical category,
but its value is saved and it can be resumed even when the category counter is
reset.

Is there a neat way to achieve this with custom counters or variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common manipulation with TeX registers looks like this:

```
\newcount\catnum
\expandafter \newcount\csname itemnum1\endcsname
\expandafter \newcount\csname itemnum2\endcsname
\def\inum{itemnum\the\catnum}

\def\bull#1{\noindent\hskip#1\parindent
            \hangindent=#1\parindent
            \llap{$\bullet$\ }\ignorespaces
}
\def\section#1{\par\bull1 \catnum=0 section #1}
\def\nextcategory{\par\advance\catnum by1 \bull2 category \the\catnum}
\def\myitem{\par
   \advance\csname\inum\endcsname by1 \bull3
   item \the\catnum.\expandafter\the\csname\inum\endcsname}
\let\resetcategories=\relax

\section{A}
\resetcategories
    \nextcategory
        \myitem{}
        \myitem{}
    \nextcategory
        \myitem{}

\section{B}
\resetcategories
    \nextcategory
        \myitem{}
        \myitem{}
    \nextcategory
        \myitem{}
        \myitem{}

\section{C}
\resetcategories
    \nextcategory
        \myitem{}
    \nextcategory
        \myitem{}
        \myitem{}
        \myitem{}

\bye
```

Comment: I had no idea that such registers existed, thanks! However, your proposition does not work since the last item ends up labeled `2.3` when I run your code whereas it should be `2.6`.

Comment: @Iago-lito It was my misunderstanding. I corrected the code.

Comment: .. which nails it now. Cheers ! ^ ^

Answer (score 3):

Something like this perhaps, using 'resuming' `enumitem` lists?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{sectionlist}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[sectionlist,1]{label={\Alph*}}
\setlist[sectionlist,2]{label={\arabic*}}
\setlist[sectionlist,3]{label*={.\arabic*}}


\begin{document}
\begin{sectionlist}
\item Section

  \begin{sectionlist}
  \item Category 
    \begin{sectionlist}[series=first]
    \item Foo
    \item Other Foo
    \end{sectionlist}
  \item Category
    \begin{sectionlist}[series=second]
    \item Foo
    \item Other Foo
    \end{sectionlist}
  \end{sectionlist}

\item Section

  \begin{sectionlist}
  \item Category 

    \begin{sectionlist}[resume=first]
    \item Foo
    \item Other Foo
    \end{sectionlist}

  \item Category 
    \begin{sectionlist}[resume=second]
    \item Foo
    \item Other Foo
    \item Yet another foo
    \end{sectionlist}
  \end{sectionlist}



\item Section

  \begin{sectionlist}
  \item Category 

    \begin{sectionlist}[resume=first]
    \item Foo
    \item Other Foo
    \item Yet another foo
    \end{sectionlist}

  \item Category 
    \begin{sectionlist}[resume=second]
    \item Foo
    \item Other Foo
    \item Yet another foo
    \item Even yet another foo
    \end{sectionlist}
  \end{sectionlist}



\end{sectionlist}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about this environment either, thanks ! I find it a little bit rigid though, since I need my items to take any form (especially regular text, paragraph with pagebreaking etc). Manipulating registers seems more neat to me.

Comment: @lago-lito: Your decision ;-) Your question wasn't pretty clear in my point of view